# Commands I can use to determine who is logged in on a specific terminal?

Tags: terminal, who, w

I am in a Linux/Unix Systems class and I need to determine commands I can use to determine who is logged in on a specific terminal? I know there is the w, who, or finger commands. Do any of these commands have options to show a user on a specific terminal or type of terminal?

Comment: See also the `ps` command's -t option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second field in the `who` command shows the console (terminal) that users are logged in on.

```
username     tty2         2017-07-16 19:05 (:0)
```

Comment: The second column is the terminal? Haha I am a beginner obviously.